# How to extract the final part of the file path in C?

Tags: c, fopen

I want to be able to find the final part of a final path and make a new file based on that. For example

```
/Users/use/Projects/projectname/test.txt
```

Based on that, i want to be able to create a new file that is called

```
test.newfile.txt
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Please state the environment. Depending on which OS you use, it might offer convenient help, e.g. `basename()`. Have look through Q/As here mentioning it.

Comment: @TheChubbyPanda Asking for a MCVE in case of a "no idea" or "howto" question is inappropriate. What gives you the impression that OP has any code?

Comment: I don't think standard C has any functions for parsing pathnames. You need to code your own or use OS-specific libraries.

Comment: That's basic string manipulation that any beginner's C text book should cover. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: @Barmar While you are generally right, it is not true that you cannot ask an appropriate question without an MCVE.

Comment: @Yunnosch True in general, but not for this kind of question.

Comment: @Barmar I am also trying to get OP to talk about their attempts...

Comment: @TheChubbyPanda comments removed, you can remove your comment, I'll remove this comment too

Comment: check `man strrchr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splice along a delimiter (here, "/"), and then grab the last element. Then create a string to use as the new filename based on that. Paraphrased from the link below;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "strtok splits once per call, call many times to split full string";
    int init_size = strlen(str);
    char delim[] = "/";

    char *ptr = strtok(str, delim);

    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        last = ptr //[p]oin[t]e[r]
        ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
    strcat("newfile.", last)

    //open a file with that name, write to it, etc.

    return 0;
}
```

source: https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/14213/how-to-play-with-strings-in-c/string-split

This will make "last" point at the last portion of the string after the final occurrence of the delimiter, so just the filename. You can then use strcat() to concatenate a string with it.

If you want you have text.newfile.txt instead of newfile.text.txt, you can split the text.txt string again, this time along the ".", and:

```
temp = strcat(original_filename, newfile)
new_filename = strcat(temp, original_file_extenstion)
```

Comment: Avoid link centric questions. Perhaps you could provide some code to explain how this can be achieved.

Comment: I feel like I would only be taking code from the link (or others). Should I still do so?

Noting also the discussion above about MCVE, is it not wise to let the questioner read some documentation themselves?

Comment: You can keep the link there but for others who find the post, it's more helpful for them if they have an actual answer on site.

Comment: Very inefficient, and modifies original string, which may not be acceptable for OP.

Comment: @qrdl how can I make it better?

Comment: @jsarbour `strrchr()`